# CriteriaBuilder compare field type with different interface implementation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using CriteriaBuilder to generate the queries to my persistent unit of the system. One of the @Entities has a field to link a class; this class is an implementation of an interface e.g.:

MyInterface
MyClassOne implements MyInterface
MyClassTwo implements MyInterface
...
(The field is called myInterface and of type MyInterface)

In one of my queries I need to verify that the type of this field is not an specific interface implementation e.g. MyClassTwo.

I found some documentation in the subject here:
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/path

I try to adapt the following exemple line to my project:

```
Predicate p = cb.notEqual(e.type(), cb.literal(Country.class));
```

So I put it like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Order> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<Order> from = criteriaQuery.from(Order.class);

Predicate p = cb.notEqual(from.get("myInterface").type(), cb.literal(MyClassTwo.class)));
```

But I get an error telling me that the column CLAZZ_ is not found:

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Column "CLAZZ_" not found; SQL statement:
select order0_.pkid as pkid3073_ [...] from *Order order0* where order0_.isDraft=? and clazz_<>?

Can you point me in the right direction to acomplish that please?

Answer (score 0):

The method described in the JPQL documentation:

```
Predicate p = cb.notEqual(e.type(), cb.literal(Country.class));
```

Translates to:

```
where clazz_=?
```

But when using the CriteriaBuilder .select(from) function, this virtual colomn is not defined. The only way is to build the query manually to fetch the virtual column "clazz_" ("1 as clazz_"); or maybe use the other query proposed in the documentation:

```
SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e WHERE TYPE(e) <> Country
```

Anyway, since I cannot write the select manually (too heavy and with autogenerated fields) nor append the .select(from) query part, I had to find a workaround.

One option is to get all th records and filter them after, inside a java loop. (too expensive when using pagination since it means processing the hole table just to know the maximum records number for the pagination).

The second option is not very pretty but it keeps the good performances. It consists in adding a "type" field in the table. To mantain the robustness of the system we should set this field private in the class and set the value atomatically in the setter of the typed field. e.g.:

```
enum MyTypes{
    MyFirstType, MySecondType
}
public interface MyInterface{}
@Entity
public class MyFisrtType implements MyInterface{}
@Entity
public class MySecondType implements MyInterface{}
@Entity
public class TableRecord{
    private String name;
    private MyInterface typedField;
    private MyTypes fieldType;

    public void setTypedField(MyInterface typedField){
        this.typedField = typedField;
        if(typedField instanceof MyFirstType)
            this.fieldType = MyTypes.MyFirstType;
        else if(typedField instanceof MySecondType)
            this.fieldType = MyTypes.MySecondType;
    }
}
```

Now the predicate construction is as simple as:

```
cb.equal(from.<MyTypes> get("fieldType"), cb.literal(MyTypes.MyFisrtType))
```